# Reduce cognitive load to create test_foo.py

Tags: python, testing

If I create a new file, let's call it `foo.py` our policy tells me to create test in `test_foo.py`.

I guess many companies have this.

Since `test_foo.py` lives in a different directory it needs some time to find the right place.

Imagine you have "foo.py" open in your IDE. It is some kind of "grrr" (at least in my head) to create the corresponding "test_foo.py".

How could the cognitive load to create `test_foo.py` in the matching directory get reduced?

[image: from-foopy-to-test-foopy]

Update 2023: I will be coding in Golang the next months. In Go it is easy, since the tests live in the same directory. If your code is in foo.go, the tests will be in foo_test.go.

Comment: Can you provide an example directory structure, to help people understand the problem?

Comment: @Michael I added an image.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your editor, there might be some plugins.
For Javascript there is an extension to vscode  that does this.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hardikmodha.create-tests

It should be possible to extend it to work for python files too.
Here is a link to the source code:

https://github.com/eskimoblood/vscode-create-test